# Why are the doctors always calling each other by their last names?

Tags: house

In Dr. House series, the doctors know each other well and are supposed to be colleagues/friends. Why not say Gregory/Robert/Eric, etc. among themselves instead of House/Chase/Foreman, etc?

Comment: I haven't watched this series, but I suspect the answer lies in the British public school system. Same reason why lots of people use surnames in, for example, *Harry Potter* (Hogwarts is a British public school with magic) or *Rumpole of the Bailey* (a barrister firm is a British public school for grown-ups).

Comment: although the possible duplicate is about a different show, it's essentially the same question with the same answer.

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate because it's about a different show.